# Finding Duration of an MP3 file in Java

Tags: java, mp3

OK so I have tried using ID3 tags to get the duration and I also tried using JMF media player.getDuration().

```
player.getDuration().getSeconds()
```

The file is VBR. Are there any light weight libraries or something inside JMF that could be used to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you get an AudioFormat object from the stream and then the combination of the sample rate and the filesize should give you the duration?

Answer (score 7):

I use JAudioTagger to achieve this. The below code will get you the duration of an MP3 track.

```
int duration = 0;

try {
  AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(new File("file.mp3"));
  duration = audioFile.getAudioHeader().getTrackLength();

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();

}
```

You can alternatively cast audioFile.getAudioHeader() to MP3AudioHeader and use the method getPreciseTrackLength() to get a more precise duration. However, this (i believe) only applies to MP3 files and no other formats (such as WAV files).

Comment: P.S! The AudioHeader (as returned by audioFile.getAudioHeader()) will also give you the MP3 file's bitrate along with a number of other properties.

Comment: Thankyou dude. 

- If you guys using gradle just use this

 

implementation group: 'org', name: 'jaudiotagger', version: '2.0.3'

Comment: Newer jaudiotagger versions use these repo coordinates: `net.jthink:jaudiotagger:<version>`

Answer (score 0):

I using this [lib](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html) and this code :

```
File f = new File("path/mp3");
    MediaLocator ml = null;
    Player p = null;
    try {
        ml = new MediaLocator(f.toURL());

        p = Manager.createPlayer(ml);
        p.start();
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Media Time :: "+p.getMediaTime().getSeconds());
            System.out.println("Duration :: "+p.getDuration().getSeconds());
            if(p.getMediaTime().getSeconds() == p.getDuration().getSeconds())
                break;
        }
        p.stop();
        p.deallocate();
        p.close();
    } catch (NoPlayerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Good luck.

Comment: When I click the link to the library, it gives a description of the library, but when I click through to download, the library described isn't actually available on the download page.  Is there a maven artifact available for this library?